# Any way to produce route values instead of query arguments when submitting a form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have the following form.

```
<form method="get">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select asp-for="@Model.MonthCode" asp-items="@Model.InvoiceDates" class="form-control">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm using the `get` method (instead of `post`) because I don't want to have to duplicate all my `OnGetAsync()` logic in `OnPostAsync()`. The two methods would do exactly the same thing. This way, I don't need `OnPostAsync()`.

However, the downside is that the data is passed as a query argument.

```
https://localhost:44322/Invoices?MonthCode=24243
```

And I would much prefer the URL:

```
https://localhost:44322/Invoices/24243
```

Is there any way to have this code produce the second URL? I prefer my users don't get a description of what the arguments are.

Comment: you can encrypt the query string

Comment: @viveknuna: Yes, I can do that. But I'm just wondering if there's any way to produce the URL I prefer.

Answer (score 1):

It feels like the cleaner solution might be to extract the code from `OnGetAsync()` into a helper method and then just call that method from `OnPostAsync()`.

Unless the implementation of `OnGetAsync()` is trivially small, Id generally avoid putting too much logic into the pages. (We tried that back in the day with web forms (.aspx pages) and it did not end well! ;-))

Comment: Yeah, I considered this. It's just that I'm still kind of new to Razor Pages, and still figuring out some of the routine stuff. So I wondered if there's a way to do what I want.

Comment: This is the correct answer. "If the method is "get" and the action is an HTTP URI, the user agent takes the value of action, appends a `?' to it, then appends the form data set, encoded using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content type." - https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3.4 Given that this is part of the HTML spec, there's no way round it.

Answer (score 0):

Put the route parameter name at the top of razor page `.cshtml` side:

```
@page "{MonthCode}"
```

and on the backend the property can be defined as:

```cs
[BindProperty(SupportsGet=true)]
public int MonthCode { get; set; }
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work for me. I already had `@page "{monthCode?}"`. I tried adding the `BindProperty` but it's not getting set (still zero). And the URL is the same. (The argument to my `OnGetAsync(int? monthCode)` is set though.)

Comment: try  without the `?` nullable

Comment: That doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Do you have endpoints enabled in startup? `app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapRazorPages(); });`

Comment: Yes. `app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapRazorPages(); });`